# How to use 'Is null' for doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two tables such as

Lesson

```
class Lesson
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\EvalMutor", mappedBy="lesson")
 */

private $evalM;
}
```

in EvalMutor

```
class EvalMutor
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Lesson", inversedBy="evalM")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lesson", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

private $lesson;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $comment;
}
```

Some lesson's rows have evalM and some don't.

I want to pick up the Lesson rows which don't have evalM.

```
SELECT p FROM UserBundle:Lesson p Where p.evalM is null
```

However it returns

```
A single-valued association path expression to an inverse side is not supported in DQL queries. Use an explicit join instead.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I guess the relationship is not correct. You have put `OneToOne` relationship, when you shoud put `OneToMany`. I'm talking about `$evalM`'s annotations.

For more info you can check [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional).